# Clear MySQL table data when Spring Boot loads

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot with Hibernate.  I'm trying to delete all the contents of a MySQL table when the server reloads.  I know it sounds dumb, but I can't really find a way to do it, probably because it sounds dumb.  Any ideas?

Comment: did you try with "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" as "create-drop"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want only a single table cleared and not all the schema you cannot use ddl-auto properties.

I suggest adding your deleteAll logic for that table to a ApplicationListener on the event ContextRefreshedEvent where you can use all spring beans (this is the difference to @PostConstructor where you can't) so you can annotate this class as spring service and use autowired in it

```
public class YourJobClass implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>{

        public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent ) {
             //Do your job
            }
    }
```

or if you don't need anything specific just do your logic in a @PostConstruct block of any class, though you need all your context to be initialized in this specific case (@PostConstruct only guarantees that autowiring is finished in the annotated bean )

Here's a list of event http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/spring-events/

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete all contents of your tables ,you can do it with adding following property in your **application.properties**. `create` property  will create all tables at the starting time

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```